# Is a billing address required by PayPal's Website Payments Pro?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, paypal, billing

I'm creating a website with rails that sells a virtual service, and therefore don't really want to validate the billing address for credit card transactions.

From what I have read on paypal (page 14 of this [pdf](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WPP_IntegrationGuide.pdf)) and other resources i have looked at, this should be totally possible.  However, when I submit a purchase or an authorize request to paypal with ActiveMerchant I get back the error "Please enter a complete billing address."

Just in case I was doing something incorrectly I copied the code from [Railscast 144](http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics) (using my own login, password, etc) Even with this code I continue to get the error.

Is there something I'm overlooking? 
Some setting I have to change on Paypal's side? 
Or is a billing address now required?

Thanks for your help

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the billing address is now required even though they do not mention it in their docs. IIRC they changed this right after I did that episode. If you check out the [next episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant) you can see billing address is required.

That said, there may be a setting to turn this requirement off, I have not looked.

Answer (score 1):

A billing address is required, and it seems kind of nonsensical that you say you don't care about the billing address because you're selling a virtual service.  Is your business model based on not caring whether someone's using a credit card fraudulently?  I don't think that's really going to work out for you, if so.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is, but the api doesn't tell you that. weird, i know. it really doesn't tell you that when you get into recurring billing too. fun times.